# How to Hide Custom Payment Method in the Checkout Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to hide custom payment method in the checkout page when we have certain brand for example: "Rolex" in the cart. The Custom payment method code is: "c1v3finance". My code in the methods.phtml is like below.

```
<?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();
    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else: ?>

    <ul class="payment-select">
<?php
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
?>
        <li>
            <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
            <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
        </li>
        <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
        <?php $formArray[] = $html; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach;
    endif;
?>
    </ul>
<?php 
    foreach ($formArray as $_form):
        echo $_form;
    endforeach;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
    payment.init();
    <?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
    payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

Please anyone help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea just to hide elements in the DOM if they should not be available.
You should not allow that certain payment method from server side.
There is an event you can use for that: `payment_method_is_active`.
Your observer for that event should look like this:

```
public function checkPaymentAvailability($observer) 
{
    $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    if ($methodInstance->getCode()  != 'your payment method code here') {
        return $this; //if it's not the payment method your a looking for do nothing
    }
    $shouldNotBeAvailable = ...your code that determines if the payment method should be available or not. 
    //you can get the items in the quote like this Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    //then loop through all of them and check if there is a product that should disable this payment method

    if (!$shouldNotBeAvailable) {
        //if the payment method should not be available then mark it as not available.
         $result = $observer->getResult();
         $result->isAvailable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom Payment method is active or available. the condition here is it has to be shown for other brands expect "Rolex" brand. Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I explained. You can hide an active and available payment method for certain conditions.